# CKEditor5 in Django

Tags: django

I search a python lib which provides CKEditor5 for django.

Unfortunately [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) will stick to version 4 for the next time.

Required features:

- provide CKEditor (including the JS-files)
- installable via pypi
- open source
- usable as django app

Related issue: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/482

Comment: I think there is [django-ckeditor5](https://github.com/pancodia/django-ckeditor5) now

Comment: @HamzDiou the github project you refer to has only one commit which is 8 months old. Does not look healthy.